# ESP12E WiFi always ON even when it should not be

Tags: iot, esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266, esp-12f

I am having a peculiar problem with ESP12E. Can someone please help me here?

I setup the ESP as an AP and running a server on it. I have configured it in a way that when I send a particular serial data, say "start", it should start the Wifi.

This is where I am facing this issue. Even before sending the serial data, the WiFi is ON. However, it does not allow data transfer. Only when I send the message "start" it allows for serial transfer.

Now my question is, why is the WiFi ON? Has anyone faced this issue? What is the solution?

Comment: probably modem is on by default during the start. Did you try to use [forceSleepBegin()](https://esp8266hints.wordpress.com/2017/06/29/save-power-by-reliably-switching-the-esp-wifi-on-and-off/)?

Comment: https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/generic-class.html?highlight=persistent#persistent